# How to set minimum width for the first column of the QFormLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlayout

How to set minimum width for the first column of the `QFormLayout`? I can do it for `QGridLayout` by using `QGridLayout::setColumnMinimumWidth(int, int)`, but cannot find a method to do that for `QFormLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set minimum width for the first column of the QFormLayout?

You cannot (off-hand). It was not designed for that as this sounds more like a `QGridLayout` feature. You could either refactor your design to use `QGridLayout`, or you could potentially set the size for the rows as you wish, but you would execute that on the row content rather than the layout itself.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple to do. Just set a minimum width on any of the widgets that you've inserted into the first column.

Comment: You can also add a row of elements with zero height and whatever widths you want to set as the minimum widths.